# Where can I find online-available datasets for the KIC 8462852?

Tags: kepler, raw-data

The question has been asked [here seven years ago](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/12142/datasets-containing-kic-8462852) but unfortunately did not receive an answer perhaps because at that time it would be reasonable to assume that no available dataset might have made it to the web.

Now, I have been searching continuously for a light curve dataset for this star containing info on the flux recorded yet the only thing I came across to is [this dataset](https://data.world/dave/tabbys-star-dimming) which contains only 52 samples perhaps collected from this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01316#:%7E:text=Over%20the%20first%20%7E1000%20days,dropping%20by%20more%20than%202%25.)

However, I have seen numerous articles such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01081) that have used the dataset from *Kepler* but I wasn't able to locate it on their website.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, apologies if my question was unclear, I am looking for a dataset for KIC 8462852 that should contain at least two of the parameters I am looking for that are time and recorded PDC flux. If there is an available open source where I can download it as a CSV format I would be very much thankful @Community

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest to follow the instructions given here: [NASA how to get Kepler lightcurves](https://www.nasa.gov/kepler/education/getlightcurves)

There you find the links to two archives, where you can enter the name of the source "KIC 8462852" and get a plot and a download link to all the Kepler lightcurves.
The normalization between these the different observations/quarters will be off due to varying observing conditions (pointing offset, focus, temperature), so you will have to normalize those, e.g. by dividing by their mean.
If you go via the [Caltech site](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/), than "Explore the archive", enter the source name and go to the "time series viewer" , they will give you the option to do that for you. And below the plot you find a button to download its data.

Not entirely sure, whether this is what you were looking for, but I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. It answers my question as I am looking for this plot for which I want to download it as a CSV format.